# DynamoDB showing error on GetItem with php sdk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am try to check what that value is available on database or not so i am using as below:

```
$domain_registrar_id = 657;
try{
$result = $dynamodb->getItem(array(
        'ConsistentRead' => true,
        'TableName' => 'domain_registrar',
        'Key'       => array(
            'domain_registrar_id'   => array('N' => $domain_registrar_id),
        )
    ));
} catch (DynamoDbException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

but its showing error as below:

Error executing "GetItem" on "https://dynamodb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://dynamodb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException","message":"Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exac (truncated...) ValidationException (client): Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes - {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException","message":"Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes"}

Answer (score 0):

considering the error, There could be two possible problems here:

1. DynamoDB does not support empty value, so you should remove those fields.
2. Field's value should have a proper data type as per the table.

Comment: I ran into the empty value problem before (over 2 year ago), you basically have to replace empty value with empty string. I did not test this again but I am surprised they seemed to have not fixed it yet.

Comment: @Gapton in [putItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) empty strings are supported now.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @samtoddler answer,
For the primary key, you must also provide all of the attributes. For example, with a simple primary key, you only need to provide a value for the partition key. For a composite primary key, you must provide values for both the partition key and the sort key.

Reference: [GetItem - Amazon DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html)